# Which anime episodes of You're Under Arrest correspond to which manga chapters?

Tags: youre-under-arrest

I couldn't find a source that tells exactly which episodes of You're Under Arrest are based on which manga chapters. I would like someone to tell me with a source because I like watching anime episodes based on which Manga I read.